# How to Render HTML string in Web Browser with Expo (React-Native)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web, expo-web

I am using `react-native-webview-quilljs` to render formatted HTML text. It works fine on Android and iOS but it isn't supported on the Web (i.e. `react-native-web`/`expo-web`). So I managed to strip the HTML tags when rendering the formatted string on the browser (i.e. rendering non formatted text).

Then I got to realise that `react-native-web` actually uses `React` to render `react-native` components on the browser. And React has something as `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` that allows injecting HTML string to be rendered directly on the browser.

So, is there a way to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` from the `react-native` / `expo` project.

Upon close inspection I found that the html tags gets converted to the html entities while rendering on the browser. Take a look at the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it (would rather call it a workaround) by rendering a `<div>` with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop when `Platform.OS === 'web'`.

Example:

```js
Platform.OS === 'web'
    ? <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: Details }} />
    : <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <WebViewQuillJS
            backgroundColor={'transparent'}
            content={Details}
            isReadOnly
        />
    </View>
```